# Authenticate https-triggered cloud functions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to have some cloud functions in firebase which are only triggerable by authenticated users, like

```
exports.samplefunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return db.collection('tests').add({
        user: req.body.id
    })
    .then(result => response.status(200).send())
    .catch(err => response.status(401).send());
});
```

How would I call this function from my client, if possible in Swift or ObjC :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include a bearer token in the https request header.

The logic is: 1) your signed in user gets a token with `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()` that is sent in the request header. Then in the cloud function, after extracting the token, you can verify it with `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` using the admin sdk.

See [this example repo from firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) or [this GCP example](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authentication-in-http-cloud-functions) for more info.